# Using node.js server for multiple simultaneous webRTC video streams

Tags: node.js, multithreading, server, stream, webrtc

I'm working on an application that involves streaming a video feed from a Microsoft Hololens to a desktop application, which I've been informed is only feasibly done using webRTC, which then integrates really well with node.js servers. My only issue here is that node.js can only handle one connection at a time when I may need hundreds of connections.

My current thought process is that perhaps I could have an array of different ports available, and the host connects to the first available port, then the client connects to the same port so long as another client hasn't already connected. Any advice on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `node.js can only handle one connection at a time` why do you think so?

Comment: That's just what information I've been able to gather. As far as I know it's not multi-threaded so one video stream would need to end before the next one would be able to begin. I'm currently just looking for any advice or resources that could point me in the right direction whether the information I have is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

nodeJS is only used to make the initial communication by using sockets, where users who want to communicate exchange information about configuration using the SDP and ICE protocol, after that the users establish a direct communication without any server, so it is a P2P communication. So NodeJS is not a limitation to make multiple video streaming. You can refer to an excellent resource to learn more about that in : https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/
https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/multiple

Good Luck